# Routing problems while upgrading form Rails 3.2.12 to Rails 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have had a Rails 3.2.12 application, now I'm gonna go updation step by step to 4.2 ... now I'm done the first step to 4.0.0 ...

Now I've got some routing problems. My pages are realized like a REST api for example

```
wwww.test.de/users/7
```

that works fine all pages where shown perfektly ... but when I want to save new data via Post it dosn't work got nil errors. ...

I've tried this to fix the Problem in the routes.rb

```
get '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
post '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

But that dosn't work ... Is there a way how to fix this problem?

Update:

Routes:

```
 XYZ::Application.routes.draw do
resources :api_users, :as => :users
resources :api_courses, :as => :courses
resources :api_uploads, :as => :uploads
get "/super_admin(/:action(/:id))", :to => "super_admin", :constraints => {:subdomain => "admin"}
get "/", :to => redirect("/super_admin"), :constraints => {:subdomain => "admin"}
get "/super_admin(/:action(/:id))", :to => "super_admin", :constraints => {:subdomain => "admin.staging"}
get "/", :to => redirect("/super_admin"), :constraints => {:subdomain => "admin.staging"}
get "/super_admin(/:action(/:id))", :to => redirect("/")
get '/' => 'pages#home'
get '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
post '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'

end
```

Controller funktion which is called:

```
 def new
@course = CourseObject.find params[:id]
return false unless check_authorization @course

add_breadcrumb_for_course_object @course
add_breadcrumb "breadcrumb.new_lesson", :action => :new
@lesson = Lesson.new params[:lesson]

puts request.request_parameters

if request.post?
  @lesson.sort = Lesson.count
  if @lesson.save
    @course.lessons << @lesson
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t "flash.saved"
    redirect_to :action => :edit, :id => @lesson.id
  end
end
 end
```

Parameters are printed like I typed in in my form ...

```
 .... "lesson"=>{"name"=>"sfsdf"}}
```

Comment: added the code above.

could that be the problem: `
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Lesson: name
        app/controllers/lessons_controller.rb:20:in `new'
`

Comment: I've added the `gem 'protected_attributes'` gem in Gemfile to solve that

Comment: does noebody have an idea?

Comment: at the moment, don't get the nil error anymore ... only this warning, WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Client:

Comment: the warninig comes in this line for example: `@lesson = Lesson.new params[:lesson]`

Comment: Sounds like you need to go with strong params or properly set up your protected attributes stuff.

Comment: do you have an example for me? thought the gem does solve the problem gem 'protected_attributes'